# Rank poker High Card hands

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer

In the poker game there are 1277 unique 'High Card' ranks. It's 1287 (13 over 5) if we include all straights.

The challenge is to write a function which returns an integer value corresponding to the rank of each 'High Card' poker combination including all straights. Possible cards are(in ascending order): '23456789TJQKA'

```
23456 -> 1
23457 -> 2
23467 -> 3
23567 -> 4
....
8JQKA -> 1285
9JQKA -> 1286
TJQKA -> 1287
```

Comment: Can we take a hand as ["10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]

Comment: isn't `23456` a straight rather a high card hand?

Comment: There are indeed 13 choose 5 = 13! / 5! / 8! = 1287 poker hands with no repeated cards (ignoring suits.) 10 of these are straights (Ace low through 10 low) . Looks like straights are not considered in the rules of this question.

Comment: How does it sort?

Comment: I said that we can include straights for simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

```javascript
x=>(y=g=(a,i=13)=>a[4]?y|=a==x:i&&g('23456789TJQKA'[--i]+a,i)+g(a,i))``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k6j0jbdViNRJ9PW0FjT1i4x2iTWvrLGNtHWtsIqU00tXUPdyNjE1MzcwjLEK9DbUT1aVzczVhuoXlM7HaRNUzMh4X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahhJYh5KmpoK@voIhFxZJc6ikERZJM5ikMaakKVzSBF3SAuQ6mJ1GFqbo8pao8mbo8iGo8ub/AQ)

```javascript
x=>(             // Input
  y=             // Init y to not-a-number (behaves as 0)
  g=             // and define a function to recurse
  (a,i=13)=>     // a is current string,
                 // i is possible chosen characters left
    a[4]?        // current string length 5
      y|=a==x    // set y to 1 if a==x, otherwise remain
                 // then returns y
                 // This counts how many times called
                 // after a==x
    :            // otherwise(length is not 5)
      i&&        // if no characters left, return 0
      g('23456789TJQKA'[--i]
          +a,i)+ // First count if the next char is chosen
      g(a,i)     // then if it isn't chosen
                 // Therefore, if all characters after X
                 // both appear or both don't appear in
                 // string P and Q, and P includes X
                 // while Q doesn't, then P is executed
                 // earlier than Q.
)``              // Calls g with [''], which behaves
                 // same as empty string.
```

Comment: What do them last two backticks do?

Comment: @Ziarek Calls the function with argument `[""]`

Comment: I'm trying to understand this algorithm and I have to say - I'm struggling. I will blame it on JS not being my primary language ;) . Would you be able to provide a non lambda equivalent if possible?

Comment: @Ziarek Maybe `function f(input){count=status=0;for(i of ['TJQKA','9JQKA',...,'23456']){if(i==input)status=1;count+=status;}return count;}`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 20 bytes

```
9RḊṾ€;“TJQKA”Ṛœc5ṚiṚ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCI5UuG4iuG5vuKCrDvigJxUSlFLQeKAneG5msWTYzXhuZpp4bmaIiwiIiwiIixbIlwiMjM1NjdcIiJdXQ==)

#### Explanation

```
9RḊṾ€;“TJQKA”Ṛœc5ṚiṚ    Main Link
9R                      [1, ..., 9]
  Ḋ                     Dequeue: [2, ..., 9]
   Ṿ€                   Un-Eval Each: "23456789"
     ;“TJQKA”           Append: "23456789TJQKA"
             Ṛ          Reverse: "AKQJT98765432"
              œc5       Combinations of length 5
                 Ṛ      Reverse
                  iṚ    Find the index of the reversed input
```

This isn't quite lexicographical order, it's sort of the opposite, so we must reverse the generation string, the combination list itself, and the input to account for this.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 105 bytes

Expects an array of characters.

```javascript
a=>(g=a=>a.some(v=>(i++&&x+1)<(x=v),i=0)?1+g(a.map(v=>i?x-i--:v)):1)(a.map(c=>"23456789TJQKA".search(c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7LCoJAGAXgfU8hLmR@zDHvFxqlba0Cd9FimNQm1BEN8e3NLhaIbQ6cw7c4N9rRljW8vmuVuKRDRgZKIpSTMSluRZmibuxcVRWlVw3Yop50sOZkA7Gh5ojiktZPwuNe45oWdgChAZ@dkUg2LdtxPT9I9sfDTsZtSht2RQwABiaqVhQpLkSOMnTCGL@1fAaQdF0yVn@ENwnzj3C/wloWzk/YS8J/vZ1@mL6zhIIZcpdQMkPe8AA)

Comment: [What does `&&x+1` do?](https://tio.run/##dc67DoIwGAXg3acgTP2DFLlfYiGuOpmwGYemAtYAJdQQ3h4NiiYEljOc8w3nQTsqWcubp16LWzbkZKAkRgV5J8VSVBnqSMw1bY960sGWkx0kplYgiivajFvS61zXow4gMuHbMxKrlu24nh@E6fF8OqhYZrRld8QAYGCilqLMcCkKlKMLxvij1SuAYhiKuVkR/iSsFeH9hL0s3L9wlkQwvp1@WIG7hMIZ8pZQOkP@8AI)